# Background VoiceOveraccessibility focus on a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, accessibility, voiceover

I have a problem with voiceover on a collectionview. I have a fullscreen (minus navigation bar) UICollectionView that contains 5 cells. Each cell contains a view with `isAccessibilityElement=true`.

When VoiceOver is activated the title in the navigation bar is focused. If I then move focus by left/right swiping each of the cell items is focused, one by one, just as one would expect. The problem is if I instead move focus by dragging my finger downwards on the screen. Then the background of the screen (i.e. the collection view's area) receive focus when the finger is outside of any of the cells.

Is there a way to turn this off?

I have tried:

```
class MyViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // A. This makes everything in the collection inaccessible, both 
        // background and cell content. 
        //collectionView?.accessibilityElementsHidden = true

        // B. This has no effect
        //collectionView?.isAccessibilityElement = false
    }  
...
```

I would expect B to work, but it doesn't (nothing happens). I've also tried various other things like: self.view.isAccessibilityElement = false, self.view.superview.isAccessibilityElement = false without success.

Hope someone can help!

Comment: It's been quite a while, have you figured it out? I have the same problem, would be a huge help if you did...

Answer (score 0):

Traversing a collection view with VoiceOver is like traversing an accessible element whose `trait` property is `adjustable`.

Each element of the collection view is an `UIAccessibilityElement` that must be redefined inside your code.

To understand how that should be implemented, I suggest you take a look at the `WWDC 2018 - Deliver an exceptional accessibility experience` video whose content is perfectly summarized [here](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-18230.html) and whose presented example can be [downloaded](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/accessibility/delivering_an_exceptional_accessibility_experience)... following this kind of programing won't focus any object in the background.

Comment: The video as well as the summary is huge, could you please quote the relevant part?

Comment: @f3dm76 : each topic of the video is detailed and points at the timelapse that it refers to. Focus on the demo that lasts few minutes. Take time to understand each point of the video if you want to solve your problem... it's sometimes necessary.

Comment: It is, but the names of the points tell me nothing about UICollectionViews or unnecessary focus for them. Could you please point out the one relevant to the issue at hand?

Comment: @f3dm76 : if the demo looks like your app should work, download the available code to take a look at it. In my view, the problem deals with what you have implemented and the way it should be done as Apple explains. Follow their path step by step and that should definitely work.

Comment: In the demo they want 'UICollectionView' to have the 'adjustable' trait and receive focus. The point of this question however is not having the trait and avoiding 'UICollectionView' ever getting the focus on itself. I only need focus to appear on couple of its cells, and never on collection itself. And what I don't get is why setting 'collectionView?.isAccessibilityElement = false' doesn't achieve that.

Comment: Create each of your collection view cell as a new accessibility element and override the 'isAccessibilityElement' according to your focus specifications. If that doesn't fit, I haven't understood the problem and I'll pass, sorry.

Comment: Cells that need it already have the focus, and they work fine. The problem is that the collectionView itself receives the focus if you tap a place not containing any of the cells. It doesn't say anything since accessibilityLabel isn't set for it. But it still draws a frame around the whole thing even if I try explicitly removing the ability to have focus for it using isAccessibilityElement. And that frame is exactly what needs to go away.